# Recyclerview is not updating when I delete items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a shopping cart where I add products, but I have a problem with it. When I push the button to delete an item, recycler view is not updated after calling also notifydatachanged(). When I navigate again to my shopping cart, the item is not there because is deleted. But I wan't to see direclty when I'm in my shopping cart activity. Here is my adapter:

```
holder.removeProduct.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            SharedPreferences preferences = mContext.getSharedPreferences(ITEMS_PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor = preferences.edit();
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String json = preferences.getString("artikujtShporta", "");
            ArrayList<Artikujt> artikullObject = gson
                    .fromJson(json, new TypeToken<ArrayList<Artikujt>>(){}.getType());

            if (artikullObject != null) {
                int indexToRemove;
                for(int i = 0 ; i < artikullObject.size(); i++){
                    if(artikullObject.get(i).getId().equals(artikulli.getId())) {
                        indexToRemove = i;
                        artikullObject.remove(indexToRemove);
                        notifyItemRemoved(indexToRemove);
                        String jsonString = gson.toJson(artikullObject);
                        mEditor.putString("artikujtShporta", jsonString);
                        mEditor.apply();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

and in my fragment:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = Objects.requireNonNull(getContext())
                .getSharedPreferences(ITEMS_PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = preferences.getString("artikujtShporta", "");
        cartItems = gson.fromJson(json,  new TypeToken<ArrayList<Artikujt>>(){}.getType());

        basketAdapter = new BasketAdapter(cartItems, getContext());
        mRecyclerView = mView.findViewById(R.id.basket_recycler_view);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity()));
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(basketAdapter);
        //basketAdapter.clear();
        //basketAdapter.addAll(cartItems);
        basketAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

`notifyDataSetChanged` here in the for loop:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < artikullObject.size(); i++){
if(artikullObject.get(i).getId().equals(artikulli.getId())) {
indexToRemove = i;
artikullObject.remove(indexToRemove);

//here
notifyDataSetChanged();
String jsonString = gson.toJson(artikullObject);
mEditor.putString("artikujtShporta", jsonString);
mEditor.apply();
}
}
```

**UPDATE**

keep what I told you and make sure that the `list` that you call on the method `.remove(indexToRemove)` is the actual list that you passed to your adapter to populate data, meaning the list that you used in `getItemCount()`

in other words:

I am not sure if `artikullObject` is the list that you must remove the object from, you must use the main list you used to populate the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Create an **`IShoppingCart`** Interface which will be implemented by your **`Fragment`**. We want to keep the logic in the **`Fragment`**. (I personally would move this logic to the **`ViewModel`** but that will be going on a tangent.)

#### IShoppingCart

```
interface IShoppingCart {
    fun addItemToCart(item: CartItem): Boolean
    fun removeItemToCart(itemId: String): Boolean

    /**
    * Feel free to add more functionality
    */
}
```

Now, pass your fragment through composition to your RecyclerViewAdapter.

#### RecyclerViewAdapter

```
ShoppingCartAdapter(val contract: IShoppingCart) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder>() {
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Now you can use this reference in your **`ViewHolder`** class as they probably are defined as **`Inner Classes.`**

#### ViewHolder

```
holder.removeProduct.setOnClickListener(v -> {
  // This will kick in the code that lies in the Fragment
  contract.removeItemToCart(viewHolder.itemView.id)
});
```

Now in your **`Fragment`**, inside the **`removeItemToCart(val itemId)`**, just remove the **`item`** with the given **`itemId`** and call **`notifyDataSetChanged()`**.

### Fragment

```
fun DeleteItemToCart(itemId: String) {
    dataset.removeItemWithItemId(itemId)
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

Following this approach, you do not need to notify the adapter that the whole data set changed, as it did not. You can simply tell the adapter that only a single element's position changed (as it was removed) by using **`notifyItemRemoved(position: Int)`**.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete an item within the adapter on within a ViewHolder view `onClick()` listener of a certain row in the RecyclerView by using `getAdapterPosition()` which returns the position of the clicked row; so you'd add:

```
artikullObject.remove(getAdapterPosition());
notifyItemRemoved(getAdapterPosition());
```

So changes in your code:

```
holder.removeProduct.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        SharedPreferences preferences = mContext.getSharedPreferences(ITEMS_PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor = preferences.edit();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = preferences.getString("artikujtShporta", "");
        ArrayList<Artikujt> artikullObject = gson
                .fromJson(json, new TypeToken<ArrayList<Artikujt>>(){}.getType());

        // remove current row of the clicked item
        artikullObject.remove(getAdapterPosition());
        notifyItemRemoved(getAdapterPosition());
    });
```

> **Update:** 
>   getAdapterPosition() is not found as a method

The `getAdapterPosition()` is a `ViewHolder` method that can not be accessed from the adapter class, so you can just transfer the `View.OnLongClickListener` to be within the custom `ViewHolder` instead of the custom `RecyclerView.Adapter` adapter.

```
class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnLongClickListener {

    View removeProduct;

    MyViewHolder(@NonNull View listItem) {
        super(listItem);
        // caching views
        removeProduct = listItem.findViewById(...);

        // Listen to removing a product 
        removeProduct.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            SharedPreferences preferences = mContext.getSharedPreferences(ITEMS_PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor = preferences.edit();
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String json = preferences.getString("artikujtShporta", "");
            ArrayList<Artikujt> artikullObject = gson
                    .fromJson(json, new TypeToken<ArrayList<Artikujt>>(){}.getType());

            // remove current row of the clicked item
            artikullObject.remove(getAdapterPosition());
            notifyItemRemoved(getAdapterPosition());

        });

    }

}
```

Note: your approach of removing a single item by iterating the entire list of items is not that good on performance, so you just need to target a certain index to be deleted.

Comment: getAdapterPosition() is not found as a method

Comment: @EraldDeveloper my fault; please check updated answer, I assumed some stuff like "MyViewModel" as it's not provided in the question.

Comment: @EraldDeveloper can you provide the code of your adapter and ViewHolder